# ERROR 503 from haveibeenpwned API

Tags: python-3.x, api

I wrote Python code that retrieves API json data from the haveibeenpwned v2 API. The code has been working flawlessly for a month or so but now when I run the code I get ERROR 503.

I searched online for the error code to my understanding this is usually caused by temporary overloading or maintenance on the server so I tried waiting. I've waited about a week trying 5-10 times a day and get the same error every time.

I used the requests Python module to retrieve the json data and to print the status code. If I get error 404 I know that the information isn't there and it goes through the loop until I get the 200 status code.

print(r.status_code)

Could this be a problem I can solve on my side or should I try to contact the owner of the API.

Edit: I realized that the website recently implemented CloudFlare DDoS protection. Could that impact the way I am trying to retrieve the data?

Comment: Make sure you are limiting your requests to 1 every 1500 milliseconds. If you post your code, that might be helpful. I don't think a 503 is an expected return code, it may be that the API was temporarily overloaded, or offline. https://haveibeenpwned.com/API/v2#ResponseCodes

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am waiting 2 seconds in between each request with time.sleep(2). I think it would give me error 429 if I exceeded their rate limit but you could be right

Comment: I have also been receiving the same problem when following the API V2 documentation. Seems to be a problem with the Cloudflare protection.

Comment: @TheHadimo Glad to know I'm not the only one having this issue. I tried contacting the owner of the API about it but I haven't heard back yet. Occasionally I'm able to receive data from the API but I'm still mostly getting Error 503.