# haveibeenpwned api returning 503 error

Tags: python, python-requests

I have the following Python code that makes a GET request to haveibeenpwned:

```
import requests

email = "example@gmail.com"

headers = {
   "User-Agent": "pwnage checker"
    }

proxies = {
    "http": my_http_proxy,
    "https": my_https_proxy
    }

req_url = "https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v2/breachedaccount/" + email + "?includeUnverified=true"
resp = requests.get(req_url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies, verify=False)

print(resp.status_code)
```

Unfortunately, I'm receiving a status code of `503`. I've read the [API documentation](https://haveibeenpwned.com/API/v2) and nowhere does it describe what a status code of `503` means. Does anyone know how I can get my API query working?

***Note:*** I know there's been a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50398859/error-503-from-haveibeenpwned-api) posted here but it's dated and I'm wondering if anyone has new information regarding this problem.

Comment: [503 is a problem on the server's end.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_errors)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you’ve triggered a defence on the Cloudflare side due to the volume of requests you were making: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003011431-5xx-Server-Error#code_503

It will pass after a while, just make sure you stay within published rate limits after that.